# Angular ng-click not fired when ng-blur added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I try to combine ng-click and ng-blur but it causes error, ng-click is not fired.

I have input and below I have list of options which I show when input is focused.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text"
    ng-model="value"
    ng-focus="onFocus()"
    ng-blur="onBlur()"
  >
  <ul ng-show="visible">
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="setValue(i)">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On items on list I defined ng-click. It set new value in model.
It works, but when I add function which hide options on input blur new value is not updated.

Here is my js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.visible = false;
    $scope.items = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"];
    $scope.onFocus = function() {$scope.visible = true;};
    $scope.onBlur = function() {$scope.visible = false;};
    $scope.setValue = function(value) { $scope.value = value; };
}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
```

Here is full sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/uqs19rea/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because of `ng-blur` function call before execute `ng-click`. so you can use `$timeout` to set `$scope.visible = false;`

```
$timeout(function(){ // ensure that $timeout injected in your controller
   $scope.visible = false;
},100);
```

**OR**

instead of use `ng-blure` you can set `$scope.visible = false;` in `$scope.setValue` function. like:

in controller:

```
$scope.setValue = function(value) { 
    $scope.value = value; 
    $scope.visible = false;
};
```

and html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-focus="onFocus()">
    <ul ng-show="visible">
      <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="setValue(i)">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `blur` event happens before the `click` event, which means the list items are already hidden when the click happens.

You can delay the hiding of the list, e.g. by using angular's `$timout` service:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.visible = false;
    $scope.items = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"];
    $scope.onFocus = function() {$scope.visible = true;};
    $scope.onBlur = function() {
        $timeout(function() {$scope.visible = false;}, 200);
    };
    $scope.setValue = function(value) { $scope.value = value; };
}
```

See the uppdated sample: https://jsfiddle.net/uqs19rea/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `onBlur` of your input is being handled before the `ng-click()` can fire ... you can test your code by changing `ng-click` to `ng-mouseover`

Comment: well `ng-mouseover` would just be a way of verifying the cause of the problem ... there are a few ways of solving this ... one method is by using a delay as shown below ... another would be to make an on-click handler for the entire page and use that instead of onBlur